# unable to parse string"19961101-11:00" at position 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

```
df['datetime_utc'] = pd.to_numeric(df['datetime_utc'])
df['datetime_utc'] = (df['datetime_utc'].replace('-',regex=True).replace(':',regex=True))
df["datetime_utc"] = Erzeugung.solar_prediction.str.replace(':').astype("float64")
```

I tried these things but not getting the result.
please help
Thank you

Comment: Your "datetime_utc" time is not numeric, may be ```pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_utc'])``` will work

Comment: Your column looks like it contains dates which pd.to_numeric raises errors by default.  You should do pd.to_datetime if you want a datetime dtype.  Or replace the hyphen and colon above pd.to_numeric